Counting points in polygons and adjacent polygons
I would like to sum up the amount of points in a polygon and in surrounding polygons adding certain weights.
Step 1. Here an example with one point: where the point is contained the weight should be for example 4; in the adjacent polygons the value assigned should be 0,5.

Step 2. It should work with multiple points within the polygons. For example - using the same values of the previous example - it should simultaneously sum up the weights of adjacent points and points within the polygon, as in the image below:


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, but you don't seem to have a problem yet. just a task. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" If your Question doesn't address these, you are likely to encounter close votes. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate what problem you have encountered.

Sum up all the points in each hexagon, then sum up the touching hexagon and add it to the final sum for each hexagon in turn

According to the question 'Counting points in adjacent polygons using QGIS', you can use the following expression proposed by the user Dror Bogin:
num_geometries( 
intersection(
    collect_geometries(
        aggregate('points',
            'array_agg',
            $geometry)
            ),
    collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('poly',$geometry))    
 ))

Example:

